# Google map places service is giving REQUEST

Tags: google-places-api

I am using google place api for places sugestions.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=ari&sensor=false&key=your_api_key

I have valid api key and this URL is working fine when I am executing it from the browser.
The api return "OK" as status and places suggestion but when I am executing the same URL by cUrl or file_get_contents It returns "REQUEST_DENIED" as status and hence no place suggestions.

why this is behaving like this.

Is there any setting which I am missing.
Any suggestion would be a great help.
Thanks

Comment: Try from the Chrome browser and use its F12 network debugger to inspect what goes in and out during the request. Then compare this to the i/o from curl. Normally I would say this sounds like a cookie issue - but in the case of Google Maps that sounds a bit strange.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever get your answer to this? As far as I am aware this is die to "cross-site-scripting" security limits. You can't go from the Places API directly to Google even though you can in a browsers address bar. You have to make the call back to your sever and have the server send the call to Google - then return those results back to your page/ web site.